# Converting string to double?

Tags: java

First off, thank you for taking time to read my question. I have three files that I am using to practice inheritance, however I have a question about converting strings to doubles. I have read the API on doubles and have an understanding that parseDouble would be the simplest way to go in terms of converting, but I am not sure where I can place parseDouble in the code provided below.

```
//Code Omitted
public Animal()
{
  name = "";
  weight = "";
  length = "";
  color = "";
}

public Animal(String n, String w, String l, String c)
{
  name = n;
  weight = w;
  length = l;
  color = c;
}

//Code Omitted The below class is an extension of my Animal class

public Dog()
{
  super();
  breed = "";
  sound = "";
}

public Dog(String n, String w, String l, String c, String b, String s)
{
  super(n,w,l,c);
  name = n;
  weight = w;
  length = l;
  color = c;
  breed = b;
  sound = s;
}

public String getName()
{
  return name;
}

public String getWeight()
{
  return weight;
}

public String getLength()
{
  return length;
}

public String getColor()
{
  return color;
}

public String getBreed()
{
  return breed;
}

public String getSound()
{
  return sound;
}

//Code Omitted
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  String name, weight, breed, length, sound, color;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please name your dog: ");
  name = input.next();
  System.out.print("What color is your dog? (One color only): ");
  color = input.next();
  System.out.print("What breed is your dog? (One breed only): ");
  breed = input.next();
  System.out.print("What sound does your dog make?: ");
  sound = input.next();
  System.out.print("What is the length of your dog?: ");
  length = input.next();
  System.out.print("How much does your dog weigh?: ");
```

Comment: There is nowhere in your code that you would *need* `parseDouble()`. If you were to add a method which does some calculation with the length or weight, you could use it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to use the `nextDouble()` method of the `Scanner` class :) So, instead of doing

```
System.out.print("What is the length of your dog?: ");
length = input.next();
```

you could use

```
System.out.print("What is the length of your dog?: ");
double length = input.nextDouble();
```

and pass that to your `Animal` class (remember to change the type of the relevant parameter though)

Comment: Thank you! I tried that earlier and I get the incompatible types error when I compile it. Edit: Ah! I did not try it with the double header :|. Java errors are always the simplest things.

Comment: well, your length variable is String, so you need to change that to double, also you need to change the relevant datatypes in your animal and dog classes :)

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to convert strings to doubles if you are using a `Scanner`: it has a method that is perfect for your purposes - [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) reads the next double, and returns it back to you:

```
System.out.print("How much does your dog weigh?: ");
if (input.hasNextDouble()) { // Add a safety check here...
    weight = input.nextDouble();
} else {
    // User did not enter a double - report an error
}
```